# Should we clarify the Tour to add 3rd party themes/plugins to the off-topic list?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed I tend to be flagging a lot of plugin questions as off-topic (often Woocommerce related).

In [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we clearly state:

> Note that we **do not handle** questions:
>
> ...
>
> - questions concerning third party plugins and themes

It's also provided as a reason to close, when flagging a post.

However in the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour), this point is not mentioned under the *Don't ask about...* section.

When I join new SE sites, I tend to read the tour much sooner than I venture through all of the help pages. I'm not sure if others are the same, but the tour is certainly more prominently linked *and* is generally much easier to digest.

**Should we add 3rd party plugins & themes as an 'off-topic reason' to the Tour page?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Agreed, we should probably review and equalize with that list with https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Will do later, unless any cons come up in discussion. :)

---

And done.

Comment: Thanks for that Rarst!